# How to handle FineUploader POST request in Java in PlayFramework?

Tags: multipartform-data, playframework-2.2, fine-uploader

I am trying to integrate FineUploader in my play framework code. View part is set up properly and it is working fine.

I am not clear how to retrieve file in my controllers upload method. And other query parameters, qquuid, qqfilename, content-type e.tc.

Following is the dump of file upload request sent by FileUploader:-

```
Request Headers

Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1021645
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/computers
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

593
------WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid"

bafb6448-1a87-40cc-abae-9624f37131cc
------WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfilename"

Test.png
------WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize"

1020995
------WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="Test.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryk8BZISBKKjjqiWQ6--
```

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFileUpload

Comment: @RayNicholus I can find the documentation on play site. I am facing problem in retrieving query parameters. If I do Map<String,String[]> queryString = request().queryString(); I am getting empty map for above posted request. As per Fine Uploader doc, these params would come in query string docs. http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html  Can you tell me how to retrieve these params ?

Comment: By default, Fine Uploader sends a multipart encoded request when uploading files. You can see this by looking at the request you pasted into your question. The link I provided will show you how to handle MPE requests using play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out by exploring play apis, sample code below.

```
    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart uploadFilePart = body.getFile("qqfile");

    String fileName = uploadFilePart.getFilename();
    File file = uploadFilePart.getFile(); 


    Map<String,String[]> dataPart = request().body().asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();

    Iterator it = dataPart.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String[] values  = (String[]) pair.getValue();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + values[0]);
    }
```

Comment: When you answer to your own question, please be more specific...like how you would like it if someone else had to answer you.

Answer (score -1):

Previous comment by me indicated there might have been something wrong with the http post fineuploader was doing, but of course that was wrong.  I was trying to adapt traditional endpoint example code into a Spring 4.x MVC controller and was getting empty FileItem list from Apache Commons FileUpload libraries.  After downloading the source for Spring and debugging through it, found that Spring MVC was using same Apache Commons FileUpload libraries to consume the http post request BEFORE it reached my controller code.  A second call to Apache's FileUpload.parseRequest returns an empty FileItem list because it was already consumed.  I had to repurpose the controller code to make use of correct signatures for request params.  I found it easiest to let the MVC framework to the parsing work for me.  I was still able to use much of the example code for traditional endpoints after refactoring for this.  For example, my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/assetUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void assetUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("qqfile") MultipartFile file) throws ServletException, IOException { ....
```

Modification of the rest of the code to produce my own class to replace FileItem (in my case called the class "FineUploaderItem"), refactor RequestParser and how the Multipart parsing was working got my server endpoint working.  I was able to use all the private methods in the UploadReceiver class in my code with very little modification after this and it all worked.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: In the example java code provided in the git repo, use of org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload is used to extract "FileItems" from the request.  The code fails to find and extract any file items using ServletFileUpload.parseRequest.  Perhaps I'm mistaken about the Content-Disposition setting of the request for the actual file item.   I have to look into that more, but there is something different in the way the HTTP post request is constructed that causes Apache request processing tools to fail on parsing it.

Comment: I reviewed another jquery library that does upload, and I am mistaken about the Content-Disposition issue, as I see "form-data" is correct, but there is something different in the way the HTTP post request is constructed that causes Apache request processing tools to fail on parsing it.

Comment: I found my own problem.  I adapted the example java code into my own project, which is Spring MVC based, which pre-parses the request before my controller code receives it.  When I used the apache libs again to parse it, it would return an empty array for FileItems.  I need to refactor my controller to use Spring's MultipartHTTPServletRequest properly.